# StatusBar barStyle not working when changing view (iOS)

Tags: ios, react-native, statusbar

I am trying to set the property `barStyle` (`light-content`) of the component `StatusBar` on my app, and it works, but only when I (re)load the app.
When changing views this property doesn't stay.

I basically have a main View, in which I have a child being a dynamic component, corresponding at the route selected, and I set the StatusBar here, which always worked, except for this property.

```
<View>
    <StatusBar
        animated={false}
        showHideTransition={'slide'}
        translucent
        barStyle={'light-content'}
    />
    <route.component
        ...
    />
</View>
```

If `route.component` is changing, the `barStyle` property goes back to its default value (`dark-content`).

I already have

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?